# Including css from other folder

Tags: php, html, css, include, directory

I would like to know whether there's an easy common way to include a css file, which is in a folder, from a html/php file inside another folder?

The structure looks like this:

- index.php
- about

  - index.php
- css

  - style.css

What I want is to know how to get the correct path to the style.css file inside the css folder from the index.php hidden in that about directory.

Comment: You need an easy way? what was the difficult way you have tried? Please share the code in your questions. For going up one level use "../" so from index.ph the link will be like this  ../css/style.css

Comment: Through $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with the project name. And it didn't really work out, but I knew there's a really easy way to do that. And the "../" is exactly what i was looking for, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going in `about/index.php`?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
```

`..` basically says, "Go up one level from where this script is located."